# Irreducible representations over a ring of $A \rtimes H$, for $A$ abelian locally compact and $H$ finite

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Assume first that $G = A \rtimes H$ is a finite group, with $A$ abelian. Serre uses Mackey's criterion and Frobenius reciprocity in his book on the representation theory of finite groups to construct all irreps of $G$ over $k$, an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, as follows.

Take a character $\chi: A \to k^\times$. Then $$\{g \in G \;\vert\; \chi(gag^{-1}) = \chi(a) \;\mathrm{for\ all}\; a \in A\}$$ is a subgroup of $G$ containing $A$, hence of the form $A \rtimes H'$. We can extend $\chi$ to $\chi': A \times H' \to k^\times$ by $(a, h') \mapsto \chi(a)$.

Now take an irreducible representation $\rho$ of $H'$ and extend it to a representation $\rho'$ of $A \rtimes H'$ by precomposing with the canonical projection. Then the induced representation of $G$ $\operatorname{Ind}_{A \rtimes H'}^G(\chi' \otimes \rho')$ is irreducible and determined up to isomorphism by $H', \chi'$ and $\rho'$. Furthermore, every irreducible representation of $G$ is of this form.

I am looking for an extension of this result in two directions. First, I would like to assume only that $A$ is abelian and discrete, not finite.
I think that Mackey's criterion and Frobenius reciprocity have been generalised to the locally compact setting, so I hope that something can be said here. Second, I would really like to allow $k$ to be an arbitrary (reduced) ring of characteristic zero, or at least $k = \mathbb Z$.

I would be grateful for any references, as well as indications where and why such a theory might fail.

Comment: Your titke says that you want to allow A to be LCA, but your question seems to only ask for A abelian and discrete. Would the second setting still be enough for you? (I don't know the answers off the top of my head, I am just trying to clarify what's being sought.)

Comment: (If you are allowing A to be LCA then surely you want to impose some continuity conditions on your representations.)

Comment: @YemonChoi sorry for the confusion -- I'd be happy with $A$ abelian and discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be any abelian group, and let $H$ be a finite group acting on $A$, and let $G=A\rtimes H$. Let $V$ be an irreducible representation of $G$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C$. Then any representation of $G$ is of the form in OP. The main technical issue is that a priori $V|_A$ may not be semisimple (consider the $2$-dimensional representation of $\mathbb Z$ where $1$ acts by $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$.) That turns out to not be a serious problem:

**Lemma 1.** If $V$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, then $V|_A$ is semisimple, and finite-dimensional.

**Proof.** Since $A\subset G$ is of finite index, $V|_A$ is finitely generated as a representation of $A$. Thus there is an $A$-equivariant homomorphism $V\to\chi$ for some character $\chi\colon A\to \mathbb C^\times$. Thus by Frobenius reciprocity there is a $G$-equivariant map $V\to\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\chi)$. Since $V$ is irreducible, this is injective. But by Mackey's formula the space $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\chi)$ as a $A$-representation is $\bigoplus_{h\in H}\chi^h$, thus $V|_A$ must be semisimple and finite-dimensional.

Now, essentially the same proof as in Serre's book runs: we have $V|_A=\bigoplus_{\chi}V^\chi$, where $\chi$ runs over the characters of $A$, and $V^\chi$ denotes the $\chi$-isotypic component of $V|_A$ (so $V^\chi$ is finite-dimensional, and is zero for all but finitely many $\chi$). At least one $V^{\chi_0}$ is non-zero. Let $H_0:=\{h\in H:\chi_0(hah^{-1})=\chi_0(a)\}$, so $V^{\chi_0}$ becomes a $H_0$-representation. Let $W\subset V^{\chi_0}$ be an irreducible sub-$H_0$-representation, so there is an equivariant map $\mathrm{Ind}_{A\rtimes H_0}^G(\chi_0\otimes W)\to V$. By Mackey's criterion the induced representation is irreducible, and hence this is an isomorphism.

---

About the second question: I don't think anything nice can be said in general. For example, when $G=S_3$, which is a semidirect product $C_3\rtimes C_2$, then over $\mathbb Q$ (or even $\mathbb Z$) the group $G$ has the $2$-dimensional absolutely irreducible representation $(\mathbb Q e_1+\mathbb Qe_2+\mathbb Q e_3)/\mathbb Q(e_1+e_2+e_3)$, where $S_3$ simply permutes the $e_i$'s.

But using Mackey's little groups method, this is the representation $\mathrm{Ind}_{C_3}^{S_3}(\chi)$, for an order $3$ character $\chi\colon C_3\to\mathbb C^\times$. The character $\chi$ certainly cannot be defined over $\mathbb Q$!